# FactoryGirl—creating variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a project where heaps of factories are like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :terms_document do
    created_by { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    updated_by { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    ...
  end
end
```

How do I create one user at the start that I can use throughout the factory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add a cache method to the factory file:

```
def user
  @user ||= FactoryGirl.create(:user)
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :terms_document do
    created_by user
    updated_by user
    ...
  end
end
```

**Update**: In a case you need different users for different factory instances:

```
def user(term_document)
  @users ||= {}
  @users[term_document] ||= FactoryGirl.create(:user)
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :terms_document do
    ...
    after(:build) do |term_document|
      created_by user(term_document)
      updated_by user(term_document)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That's beautiful, thanks. One question—if the factory is for a company that the user should belong to, how would you set the foreign id so that `user.company` refers to the company being built?

Comment: If I understand your question right, you want every company object to use only one user object, and two different companies should use different users (because one user object can't belong to two different companies)?

Comment: I want different companies. Each company should have different users. However, every reference to a user within a company should be the same user, to save 1000s of users being created. Is this possible?

Comment: Your current answer, does that cached method persist across different instances of the factory?

Comment: Yes, the current solution caches `user` for all instances of the `factory`.

Comment: How do I make a `user` only for the one factory instance? Yet accessible anywhere in the instance?

Comment: I've added this case to the answer, pls check.